# Handle data received from a payload

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, uilocalnotification

I am using fcm to send payload data to my app (not a notification).
I am using the method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

to handle data received and then i display a Local notification.
Local notification is displayed when app is in foreground and background, but when app is closed (terminated), the Local notification is not getting displayed. 
I am using :

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
```

To handle logic for the data received after user tap the local notification.
Any ideas why the Local notification is not displayed when the app is totally closed?

Comment: what you mean by `local notification` , are you create local notification when  user press FCM notification

Comment: No, after app receive userinfo from data payload sent, i am displaying a local notification, this is working good when the app in foreground and background, but it seems that the data payload is not received when app is terminated

Comment: you not receive `notification` when app is terminated , or when you press notification when app is terminated  you can't set local notification from payload

Comment: Only when the user force close app. Any ideas how to solve this? The app is not receiving a notification, it only receive a payload data,

Comment: So you not receive notification when user force close app

Comment: Only payload data is send to app, no Notification is sent , here is an example of my payload: {
 "content_available":true,
 "priority":"high",
 "data":{
  
  "message_title": "test message title",
  "message":"test message body",
  "message_image_url":"https://myimageurl",
  "item_key":"ybAfB3ylh",
  "itemt_type":"Video"
 },
 "to": "tokenid"
}